# The positional input parameter ''{0}'' cannot use non-Integer characters

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, soap

I am facing the following  probleme in my JPA Entity during the runtime.

"`The positional input parameter ''{0}'' cannot use non-Integer characters`"

JPA CODE:

```
      @NamedQuery(name = "tableName.findMenueByBenutzerIDAndMandatID",
                  query = "select m from DOMenueVerwaltung m " + " where  m.menue=?EN"),
```

What can be the cause of this?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: that input parameter {0} contains a non-integer. Where's the code?

Comment: @bicycle Pleas se post for the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPQL supports either **named** parameters (*":myParam"*) or **numbered** parameters (*"?1"*, *"?2"*). What you have there is neither (a question mark symbolising numbered parameter, but with a name after rather than number). Suggest reading any decent JPA docs